# postgres query record by specific date

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

was using postgres..

I got the columns similar like below

```
start_time: "2013-11-30 03:51:00"
```

But I having date which ruby generated

```
Date.today ->  Mon, 16 Dec 2013
```

How do I trigger records that fall on the day?

```
select * from records where start_time = ?
Record.where("start_time = ?", Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about comparing the date?

```
Record.where("start_time >= ? and start_time < ?", Date.today, Date.today + 1)
```

`Date.today + 1` is the beginning of next day